# react on events generated by chaco tools: how to get values out of a chaco tool when an event is fired ?

Tags: traits, enthought, chaco

actually this should be a pretty simple question, but I am experiencing the quite steep learning curve of chaco and traits...

I am currently writing an application to plot a medical image using chaco and traits and I simply want to pick a pixel location from the image and use this pixel location to do evaluations on an image stack. So I started to write my own Chaco Tool that reacts on mouse clicks on an imageplot.
This works fine so far. When I click on the imageplot I can see the mouse coordinates WITHIN the Tool (a custom made PixelPickerTool). However, as I want to use this coordinate value outside the tool my question would be: How can I hand the coordinates over to another object or variable OUTSIDE the Tool when an event is fired.

To illustrate what I want to do I attached the main structure of the two classes I am Writing:

```
class PixelPickerTool(BaseTool):
    '''Pick a Pixel coordinate from an image'''

    ImageCoordinates = [0,0]

    def normal_left_down(self, event):       
        print "Mouse:", event.x, event.y,
        click_x, click_y = self.component.map_data((event.x, event.y))
        img_x = int(click_x)
        img_y = int(click_y)
        coord = [img_x, img_y]
        if ( (img_x > self.ImageSizeX) or (img_x < 0) ):
             coord = [0,0]
        if ( (img_y > self.ImageSizeY) or (img_y < 0) ):
             coord = [0,0]

        print coord
        # this print gives out the coordinates of the pixel that was clicked - this works fine...
        # so inside the picker too I can get the coordinates
        # but how can I use the coordinates outside this tool ?


class ImagePlot(HasTraits):
    # create simple chaco plot of 2D numpy image array, with a simple interactor (PixelPickerTool) 
    plot = Instance(Plot)
    string = String("hallo")
    picker = Instance(PixelPickerTool)

    traits_view = View(
        Item('plot', editor=ComponentEditor(), show_label=False,width=500, height=500, resizable=False),
        Item('string', show_label=False, springy=True, width=300, height=20, resizable=False),
        title="")   

    def __init__(self, numpyImage):
        super(ImagePlot, self).__init__()
        npImage = np.flipud(np.transpose(numpyImage))

        plotdata = ArrayPlotData(imagedata = npImage)

        plot = Plot(plotdata)
        plot.img_plot("imagedata", colormap=gray)

        self.plot = plot
        # Bild Nullpunkt ist oben links!
        self.plot.default_origin = 'top left'

        pixelPicker = PixelPickerTool(plot)
        self.picker = pixelPicker
        plot.tools.append(pixelPicker)
```

I want to use the coordinates that are measured by the PixelPickerTool somewhere in this ImagePlot class. E.g. by handing them over to another Object like MyImageSeries.setCoordinate(xy_coordinateFromPickerTool)
So how can I hand over the pixel coordinates from PickerTool to some member variable in this class when an event is fired ?
Maybe something like this: self.PixelCoordinates = picker.getPixelCoordinates() could work ?
But how do I know then, when the on_normal_left_down function was executed in the picker ?

In the end I want to hand the coordinates over to another class which hold more images to process the images and do a fit at the pixel position determined in the ImagePlot.
I tried  to use something like "_picker_changed" in my imagePlot class to detect if an event has been fired in the PickerTool, but this didn't detect event firing. So maybe I am doing something wrong...

Can anybody tell me how to get events and associated variables out of this picker tool ?

Cheers,

Andre

Answer (score 1):

"But how do I know then, when the on_normal_left_down function was executed in the picker?"

There are several ways you could probably do this, but one way would be to simply do exactly what you are asking and fire an event that you define explicitly.

for instance:

```
from traits.api import Event

class PickerTool(BaseTool):
  last_coords = SomeTrait
  i_fired = Event

  def normal_left_down(self,event):
     # do whatever necessary processing
     self.last_coords = do_some_stuff(event.some_attribute)
     # now notify your parent
     self.i_fired = True
```

and then listen to plot.picker.i_fired from wherever you want to display, and look in plot.picker.last_coords for the saved state.

Another thing you can do that may be simpler if what you want to do with these coordinates is very straightforward, is just pass on intialization the data structures the picker needs to interact with (or get them with a chain of calls to self.parent) and do your work directly inside the picker.